# Uploading and image dynamically at runtime in Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I am building a form builder in Flex 4.5. For that I need help regarding uploading image at runtime such that any user can just simply place cursor on particular location on image and is able to upload any image from the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using native extension or native process. But this is only possible with AIR.
Here is a simple example:
http://thanksmister.com/2011/03/16/upload-s3-curl-air-nativeprocess/

I hope this helps :)

Could you describe more what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for help......i am trying to add image with the help of browse() and load() methods in flex 4.5 also using loaderContentInfo() so that its easy to upload image in form at run time & also images can be saved from form site to our local system.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple

```
        private function browseForFile():void
        {
            fr = new FileReference();
            fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,handleBrowseForFileSelected);
            fr.browse([]);
        }

        protected function handleBrowseForFileSelected(event:Event):void
        {           
            fr.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT,handleBrowseForFileSelected);

            fr.upload( ...)
        }
```

in fr.upload fill the parameters as you need, basically a URLRequest to which you will upload the file to.